# Problem with performing a certificate http client call : "Request canceled: unable to create secure TLS / SSL communication"

Tags: c#, rest, ssl, x509certificate, dotnet-httpclient

I explain the situation to be clearer: I have a wcf service that contains an internal manager that makes rest calls to another service. To make these calls, the external service requires a certificate (consider that the certificate used is valid). The problem is that when I try to call an http client call to this service an exception is thrown: "Request canceled: unable to create secure TLS / SSL communication". I tried different solutions but I could not solve the problem, and I hope someone can help me. Below is the code of the internal manager that makes the call.

```
try
        {
            WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();

            handler.ClientCertificates.Add(getCertificate());

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=

                (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var input = new 
            {
                id = 90,

                version = Convert.ToInt32(Version),

                network = Convert.ToInt32(Id),

                list = List
            };

            var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(_endpoint, input);

            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {

                throw new Exception($"Error code: {response.StatusCode}");

            }

            var returnedData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception($"{ex.Message}\n{ex.StackTrace}");
        }
```

Note: consider that the "getCertificate" method returns the correct certificate

Comment: Have you tried to look at the traffic with wireshark or another network traffic analyser?

Comment: Yes, I was able to communicate with the server, and I successfully ran client-hello and server-hello, but then I get the exception mentioned in the problem description. I used wireshark.

Comment: Who is closing the connection and what is the payload in the fin package, it will most probably contain an error message. If not, look at the previous package send. 

There is a lot that can go wrong in this case, the server certificate can be invalid or untrusted by your local machine or the other way around.
There can be an issue with ssl versions used by server and client.
Most of these issues can be revealed by taking a close look at the traffic between the two machines.